# siber.ellipses -> Error in rmultireg(Y, X, Bbar, A, nu, V) : not a matrix

Tags: r, error-handling

I am very new to R and am currently trying to create siber ellipses.

I watched the potcast Using ellipses to compare community members:(http://www.tcd.ie/Zoology/research/research/theoretical/Rpodcasts.php#siber) and got along just fine in the beginning. Whenever i get to the function of the siber.ellipses i get an Error:
(Error in rmultireg(Y, X, Bbar, A, nu, V) : not a matrix)
I can not figure out why. I get it with my own data as well as with the example data in the zip file provided along with the script.

I have researched the Error message online but could not come up with an answer.

It almost can be an error in the script or the data since I used those exactly as provided. My R version is 3.3.2
Does it have something to do with some kind of settings?
What could be the reason?

Can someone please helpe me :)

thanks

```
# this demo generates some random data for M consumers based on N samples and
# constructs a standard ellipse for each based on SEAc and SEA_B

rm(list = ls())

library(siar)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ANDREW - REMOVE THESE LINES WHICH SHOULD BE REDUNDANT
# change this line
setwd("C:/Users/elisabeth/Desktop/R/demo")

#     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# now close all currently open windows
graphics.off()

# read in some data
# NB the column names have to be exactly, "group", "x", "y"
mydata <- read.table("example_ellipse_data.txt",sep="\t",header=T)

# make the column names availble for direct calling
attach(mydata)


# now loop through the data and calculate the ellipses
ngroups <- length(unique(group))



# split the isotope data based on group
spx <- split(x,group)
spy <- split(y,group)

# create some empty vectors for recording our metrics
SEA <- numeric(ngroups)
SEAc <- numeric(ngroups)
TA <- numeric(ngroups)

dev.new()
plot(x,y,col=group,type="p")
legend("topright",legend=as.character(paste("Group ",unique(group))),
    pch=19,col=1:length(unique(group)))

for (j in unique(group)){


  # Fit a standard ellipse to the data
  SE <- standard.ellipse(spx[[j]],spy[[j]],steps=1)

  # Extract the estimated SEA and SEAc from this object
  SEA[j] <- SE$SEA
  SEAc[j] <- SE$SEAc

  # plot the standard ellipse with d.f. = 2 (i.e. SEAc)
  # These are plotted here as thick solid lines
  lines(SE$xSEAc,SE$ySEAc,col=j,lty=1,lwd=3)


  # Also, for comparison we can fit and plot the convex hull
  # the convex hull is plotted as dotted thin lines
  #
  # Calculate the convex hull for the jth group's isotope values
  # held in the objects created using split() called spx and spy
  CH <- convexhull(spx[[j]],spy[[j]])

  # Extract the area of the convex hull from this object
  TA[j] <- CH$TA

  # Plot the convex hull
  lines(CH$xcoords,CH$ycoords,lwd=1,lty=3)


}

# print the area metrics to screen for comparison
# NB if you are working with real data rather than simulated then you wont be
# able to calculate the population SEA (pop.SEA)
# If you do this enough times or for enough groups you will easily see the
# bias in SEA as an estimate of pop.SEA as compared to SEAc which is unbiased.
# Both measures are equally variable.
print(cbind(SEA,SEAc,TA))

# So far we have fitted the standard ellipses based on frequentist methods
# and calculated the relevant metrics (SEA and SEAc). Now we turn our attention
# to producing a Bayesian estimate of the standard ellipse and its area SEA_B


reps <- 10^4 # the number of posterior draws to make

# Generate the Bayesian estimates for the SEA for each group using the 
# utility function siber.ellipses
SEA.B <- siber.ellipses(x,y,group,R=reps)
```

Error in rmultireg(Y, X, Bbar, A, nu, V) : not a matrix

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the SIAR package using Jackson's Github site:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("andrewljackson/siar@v4.2.2", build_vingettes == TRUE)
library(siar)
```